# How to get sms list from iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

I want to get sms list, which are sent, received, drafts in iPhone device as array or .db or dictionary in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get access to these resources, you only have access to files inside your app folder.
If the device is jailbroken, you may have a way like some apps in Cydia.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it unless the device is jailbroken, the path to the sms.db is

```
/private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db
```

which obviously accessible only on jailbroken device. Being a database file, obviously you can do something to it. Haven't really tried myself but,

```
select * from message;
```

should give you all the message. Not what you want, but I think this is informational.